# React Native Parse.com android push notifications

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

While there is an excellent sample enterprise mobile app using React Native and the [Realtime Platform](https://github.com/realtime-framework/RCTRealtimeNews), I don't see any for Parse.com.

Im having trouble using push notifications in Android using React Native, what currently works for me is adding the below code to Android Project.

```
Parse.initialize(this, "key", "token");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

But in this case I would be calling Parse.initialize twice once in Android onCreate() and again inside ReactNative to fetch the query results. Im not sure if this is the right way to do. Also i dont see a way to use ParseInstallation object inside ReactNative.

Another problem is on subscribing individual channels from ReactNative. This can be done by using the RESTAPI requests, but requires the DeviceToken which again is not available inside react-native.

Thanks

Comment: Are you only intending to use push notifications?

Comment: I also use the parse queries to get data inside react native , but yes currently I'm having trouble with push notifications using parse.com & react native, especially for android.